# Добавление элемента в избранное без использования БД

Tags: android

Есть приложение, в котором реализован вывод элементов в `RecyclerView`. Данные в него выводятся из `json` из папки `assets`. Хочу реализовать добавление некоторых элементов в избранное, но использовать базу для этого не хочу, т.к. количество элементов небольшое. Какие есть способы это реализовать. Первое что в голову пришло это добавить в `json` новый пункт и заполнить его нулями, а при добавлении в избранное заменять 0 на 1. Правильный ли это способ или что-то получше можно придумать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

насколько я знаю вы не можете изменить программно файл из assets

если не хотите использовать бд, то попробуйте хранить данные например в SharedPreferences

например создать функцию

```
public static void setFavor(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    if (context != null && context.getPackageName() != null && PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) != null) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean(key, value).commit();
    }
}
```

и записывать туда id элементов json

```
setFavor(context, "favor_"+id, true);
```

и так же читать

```
public static boolean isFavor(Context context, String key) {
    if (context != null && context.getPackageName() != null && PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) != null) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, false);
    } else return false;
}


boolean mIsFavor = isFavor(context, "favor_"+id);
```

---

**Дополнил**

Полностью удалить переменную SharedPreferences можно так

```
public static boolean deletePref(Context context, String key) {
    if (context != null && context.getPackageName() != null && PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) != null) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().remove(key).commit();
    }
    return false;
}

deletePref(context, "favor_" + id);
```

Для удаления всех "избранных" можно использовать цикл, его же можно переделать что бы вывести все переменные "избранных"

```
public static void deleteAllPrefStartWith(Context context, String template) {
    Map<String, ?> keys = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (key.startsWith(template)) {
            deletePref(context, key);
        }
    }
}

deleteAllPrefStartWith(context, "favor_");
```

Comment: Спасибо. буду пробовать.

Comment: Сработал ваш код. А как возможно удалить из избранного таким образом? или узнать id всех избранных?

Comment: Наверное удаление будет как-то так? SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        preferences.edit().remove("favor_" + id).apply();

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна, да, id всех избранных можно узнать перебрав все SharedPreferences и выделив те, которые начинаются на "favor_" (дополнил ответ)